# Making a background image remain correctly positioned

Tags: html, css

I have a site where a centred background image plays a vital part in a homepage animation.

The background centres great until the browser window cannot fit in the width of the site, at which point the background kind of left aligns.

This is my body code:

```
body {
line-height:1;
margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;
background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

The image popups shoot out from the correct place on the bg image. Try making the browser window smaller and you will see what i mean, the bg moves out of alignment.

I want the houses to stay in the correct position at all times.

thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your body keeps resizing while your content doesn't at 1050px. Since the background is applied to the `body`, you need to change the background position using a media query at that value.

The best way to do so would be to realign it based on a left value, you can set it to be more specific than this using pixel, but I am not sure where exactly in the image want it placed

```
@media (max-width:1050px) {
    body {
        background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat left top;
        /* Possible background-position property here */
    }
}
```

As a front end designer, I would recommend not donig this but rather using media queries to affect your layout to respond to smaller window sizes (become responsive), but that is a different issue

Comment: hi zach that just might work, how to i specify if its larger than 1050 for the other normal background setting? or is there an esle type command? cheers

Comment: @user3301415 If you leave the code as it is it should work. Media queries are only applied when their condition is met, thus this one only affects the page when the viewport is less than 1050px. In essence it defaults to the original but uses this when the viewport width < 1050px. Try adding my code to your CSS page to see if it works

Comment: hi zach, i added it but unless i remove the line:
 background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat center top;  
it didnt work, when i remove the line your css works but if it goes over 1050 bg is blank.

Comment: @user3301415 This is because of the CSS specificity of the selector then. You could either add an ID to the body and use that as the selector instead or you could add `!important` before the semicolon. Make sure the original code is still in the CSS file

Comment: media all and (max-width:1050px) {
    body {
        background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat left top;
        background-position:-479px 0;
    }
}
media not all and (max-width:1050px) {
 body {
 background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat center top;
 }
}

that worked but will older browsers (or incompatible with media tag) show a BG image at all now?

PS> i had to remoave the (at) signs wouldnt let me post them here

Comment: @user3301415 You should just need `@media all (max-width:1050px) { body { background:#90a830 url(img/bg.png) no-repeat left top !important; background-position:-479px 0; } }`, not the second part. Support for media queries go back to [IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20qu). Browsers will show the original image if they don't support media queries. If you need to reach further with full functionality you can do the same using javascript's `window.innerHeight` and some other code

Comment: thanks Zach but if i do what you say its blank when site gets over 1050px wide. Thats in chrome. can you give me the full media and backup body command as a fallback. seems to be like saying "if site is 1050px or less then show the backhround image" with no else.

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

thanks to Chris Coyier: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: This doesn't work, try it yourself

Comment: No it didn't work - it destroyed the site layout